# RPScreenRecorder startCapture is not recording in background

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I am trying ScreenRecording implementation using Replaykit. It is currently able to record app screen, but when I am putting it in background for device screen recording, then `RPScreenRecorder.startCapture` callback is not getting called.

```
let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

recorder.delegate = self
recorder.startCapture(handler: { (buffer, bufferType, err) in
      self.counter = self.counter.advanced(by: 1)
      print(self.counter)
//    self.assetWriter.write(buffer: buffer, bufferType: bufferType)
   }, completionHandler: {
   if let error = $0 {
      print(error)
   }
 })

// stop recording

recorder.stopCapture {
   if let err = $0 {
       print(err)
   }
// self.assetWriter.finishWriting()
}
```

Do we need to allow any permissions for background access.

Comment: https://github.com/StraaS/StraaS-iOS-sdk/wiki/Live-Streaming-with-Apple's-ReplayKit

Comment: Broadcast extension Is what you need

Comment: already done that too.

Comment: Actually I dont want to broadcast it right now, just like iOS ControlCenter is saving that video in photolibrary, same thing I want to do.

Comment: @AnkitThakur did you solve this? I just wanna record the video in the local device, no broadcast to any server

Comment: @PabloMartinez yes, I have achieved it. When we are getting sample buffer from broadcast extension, then we are saving it in keyarchiever and then processing them from main app.

Comment: @AnkitThakur yeah I did finally the same, use the broadcast upload extension :)

Comment: @PabloMartinez if you want any reference, you can check detailed answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742537/499351